# How to set IAM roles root path

Tags: amazon-iam

I have created an IAM role named ab-role. The default path for this role is /.
I wanted to change the path to something like /service-role/. How is it possible to change the root path of IAM role.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe you can "change" the path of an existing role -- it's an intrinsic part of the object. You have to specify it when the role is initially created.

Here's a possible reason why you're not finding a way to set it:

> Paths cannot be created or manipulated in the AWS Management Console. To use paths you must work with the resource by using the AWS API, the AWS CLI, or the Tools for Windows PowerShell.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html